# How can take value request DTOs in my service @PutMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, crud

I'm trying to do an @PutMapping where I would put all the logic to change the attributes inside the service but I ran into a problem. How could I get the values from my requestDTO to play inside the class and make these changes inside the service and not in the controller?

The request data is the same as the response and class

```
private Long id;


private String program;
```

my controller and service implements

```
 @PutMapping(value = "/edit-program/test/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ProgramResponseDto> updateProgramByIdTest (
            @PathVariable(value = "id") final Long id,
            @Valid @RequestBody final ProgramRequestDto programRequestDto) throws UpdateDataException {

        ProgramResponseDto programResponseDto = ProgramMapper.INSTANCE.programToProgramResponseDTO(
                programService.Update(id));

        log.info(LocaleContext.format("response.success",
                (new Object() {
                }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName()),
                HttpStatus.OK.toString()));

                return status(HttpStatus.OK).body(programResponseDto);

    }

  @Override
    public Program Update(Long id) throws UpdateDataException {

    Program program = null;

    try {

        Optional<Program> programDB = programRepository.findById(id);

        if (programDB.isPresent()) {

            program = programDB.get();

            ProgramRequestDto programRequestDto = ProgramRequestDto.builder().build();
            program.setProgram(programRequestDto.getProgram());
            program.setId(programRequestDto.getId());

            return programRepository.save(program);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new UpdateDataException(e.getMessage());

    }
    return null;
}
```

service
Program Update(Long id) throws UpdateDataException;

Comment: Pass the dto down the line.

Comment: Just pass the dto to the `Update` method, and inject the service to your controller then call the Update method from your service.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really didn't realize, when I pass the dto I can pick it up and work with it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the signature of the Service method to accept `ProgramRequestDto` as follows:

```java
public Program Update(ProgramRequestDto programRequestDto) throws UpdateDataException
```

And update the Controller accordingly:

```java
@PutMapping(value = "/edit-program/test/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ProgramResponseDto> updateProgramByIdTest (
         @PathVariable(value = "id") final Long id,
         @Valid @RequestBody final ProgramRequestDto programRequestDto) throws UpdateDataException {

     ProgramResponseDto programResponseDto = ProgramMapper.INSTANCE.programToProgramResponseDTO(
             programService.Update(programRequestDto));

     log.info(LocaleContext.format("response.success",
             (new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName()),
             HttpStatus.OK.toString()));

     return status(HttpStatus.OK).body(programResponseDto);
}
```

Not sure if this is what you want but it is what I understood from your question.

Comment: Thank you very much João, I hadn't been able to look at it that way and that's exactly what I wanted to do. thank you very much for clarifying